# Select filtered sums with joins MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

I am developing a bets system and basically there is a set of matches (or games). The matches always has 2 teams on which the users can bet.

I have the following DB structure:

**matches:**

[image: Table "matches"]

**teams:**

[image: Table "teams"]

**bets:**

[image: Table "bets"]

What I am trying to do with my query is bring from the database the matches and the bets's amounts sum, related to each team, in each match and list all the matches with all the information related to it.

**The far I was:**

```
$query="SELECT 
a.*, 
SUM(b.amount) AS sumA, 
SUM(c.amount) AS sumB, 
d.name AS teamNameA, 
e.name AS teamNameB 
FROM matches AS a 
LEFT JOIN bets AS b ON(a.teamA = b.team_id AND a.id = b.match_id)
LEFT JOIN bets AS c ON(a.teamB = c.team_id AND a.id = c.match_id)
LEFT JOIN teams AS d ON(a.teamA = d.id)
LEFT JOIN teams AS e ON(a.teamB = e.id) GROUP BY id"

$result = mysql_query($query);

$resultArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $resultArray[] = $row;
}

print_r($resultArray);
exit();
```

**What is printed:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [teamA] => 1
            [teamB] => 2
            [teamNameA] => "Team 1"
            [teamNameB] => "Team 2"
            [sumA] => 400
            [sumB] => 200
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [teamA] => 1
            [teamB] => 2
            [teamNameA] => "Team 1"
            [teamNameB] => "Team 2"
            [sumA] => 
            [sumB] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [teamA] => 1
            [teamB] => 2
            [teamNameA] => "Team 1"
            [teamNameB] => "Team 2"
            [sumA] => 
            [sumB] => 
        )
)
```

It is almost perfect, but the amounts in "sumA" and "sumB" itens of the first row is wrong. "sumA" should be equal 200 and "sumB" should be equal 100. Of course it is duplicating the sum process. I tried to use the "DISTINCT" statement within the SUM's but them, it eliminates the amount's equal values and I get 100 for "sumA" and 50 for "sumB", what still wrong as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint of @SKRocks, I finally found the correct solution, substituting the bets table's LEFT JOINs for subqueries as following:

```
$query="SELECT 
a.*, 
(SELECT sum(D.ammount) FROM bets AS D WHERE D.match_id=a.id AND D.team_id=a.teamA) AS sumA, 
(SELECT sum(E.ammount) FROM bets AS E WHERE E.match_id=a.id AND E.team_id=a.teamB) AS sumB, 
d.name AS teamNameA, 
e.name AS teamNameB 
FROM matches AS a 
LEFT JOIN teams AS d ON(a.teamA = d.id)
LEFT JOIN teams AS e ON(a.teamB = e.id) GROUP BY id";
```

Now I get the correct results and maintained the LEFT JOINS for performance. I am choosing this answer as the final solution, because it is what I am actually using. But you gave me the right hint to build this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution for you that includes sum(amount), ID of the team, and the team Name.

```
SELECT SUM(amount), bets.id, teams.name from bets
INNER JOIN teams ON bets.team_id = teams.id GROUP BY teams.id;
```

It is not the same as what PHP printed, but I find it more useful.

You might as well look at this SQLFiddle I wrote.

Good luck.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ffc6/17

Comment: Thank you Linial, but i have to relate it by the matches, not by the bets, because i want to list all the matches and relate these infos in the list. But i appreciate your hint.

Comment: Moreover, i have other match-related infos that i must include with other joins that i did not posted to make the epicenter of the issue clearer

Comment: SKRocks's subqueries solution fits the proposal. I built the actual solution with his hint and posted it below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this sql

```
SELECT  A.id as match_id, A.teamA as teamA, A.teamB as teamB, 
        (SELECT B.name FROM teams B WHERE B.id=A.teamA LIMIT 1) AS teamNameA, 
        (SELECT C.name FROM teams C WHERE C.id=A.teamB LIMIT 1) AS teamNameB, 
        (SELECT sum(D.amount) FROM bets D WHERE D.match_id=A.id AND D.team_id=A.teamA) as sumA , 
        (SELECT sum(E.amount) FROM bets E WHERE E.match_id=A.id AND E.team_id=A.teamB) as sumB 
FROM `matches` A
```

this is too lengthy and get some time to execute but you will get output according to your choice

Comment: Thank you man! I've been 2 days trying to doing that. LoL.

I also maintained the LEFT JOIN's of the team table's SELECT's for performance and substituted only the bets table's SELECT's by your subqueries. I will post the solution. Thank you again!